# Handling Model Dialogs in IE through Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I have a application in which my pop-ups appear as Model Dialogs. My Application works only in IE.

No matter what different types of switches I use (switchToActiveContent, switchToWindow, switchtoFrame) I'm not able to switch my control to the new Model Dialog.

The solutions I've overcome is- Handling the Model Dialog through Robot Classes. But, I don't want to just handle and close the popup but perform actual operations and functions on it (my model pop-up has Web objects inside it)

Is there a definitive solution for this? Can Selenium WebDriver can't handle Model Popup dialogs at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code

```
string BaseWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I can switch to the Window that is open but I cannot handle any objects inside it since it is a Model dialog.

Comment: Hope, below code will work

if (driver.WindowHandles.Count > 1)
{
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);
}